# Latex scrreprt redefine subsubsection

Tags: latex

How to solve this problem: I use the `scrreprt` to build an elaboration. In this I use `subsubsection`. I want to number this in the paper, but don't see it in the tableofcontents. At the moment it is not in the tableofcontents(thats good), but in the paper it is not numbered(like 3.1.1.1). How to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable numbering of subsubsections, add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` to the preamble.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Sub Section}
\subsubsection{Sub Sub Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add subsubsections to the TOC using: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`